# sse with push notification in a pwa

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, server-sent-events

I am trying to integrate push notification in a web app(also PWA). I am using `Mercure`(https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html) to send notification to users.

The webapp is made using Angularjs and PHP-symfony. I think for SSE the connection should remain open or re open every few seconds to send an event.

I don't know if it will work for PWA. Can I send a push notification using SSE to a PWA even when it's not open? If not, what should I use to send a push notification.

Should I use websockets? All the libraries for websockets I've seen create channels. And I don't know how to send a notification to a particular user in my database because in websocket, the only way to distinguish a user is a sessionId that's generated when they join the channel.

I will probably have to save the sessionId of the user in database when they login and join a common channel in the application and find sessionId of users I want to send a notification to and then send.

My question is, if I use SSE, can I send push notification when the webapp or PWA isn't open. Will websockets help? If yes, please give a suggestion on how I do what I want to do.

Comment: have you got any resolution?